# Flutter error loading background Image onto app

Tags: flutter, yaml

I am attempting to add a background image to my app. I am using Flutter and Visual Studio. However, I keep getting this error. I have tried everything from flutter clean and changing all my indentations on the YAML files multiple times. I have also tried to change the image files to see if anything would work. Any help would be appreciated.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI5qw.png)

[insert image method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emkfa.png)

[YAML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBQ1o.png)

Comment: Please do not add errors and codes as images. Read the how to ask. To get an best answer, edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forward slash (/)` in the path you are providing to `AssetImage()`

Example - `AssetImage("lib/assets/someimage.png")`

Answer (score 0):

I recomendation is to first to change the YAML file to this way:

```
Assets:
   lib/assets
```

This way you dont have to specify all the files in the assets folder.
Then as Sachin says, uses the forward slash to complete the relative path.
Another workaround will be to create the asset folder in the root project and then move you images over there.

P.D: sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you used the wrong slash.
You should use `/` instead of `\`.

Usually, the `\` is used as an escape character, like `\n` for a new-line.
Note that these characters are highlighted in your IDE with a different color.

So your code will be:

```
    ...
    image: AssetImage('lib/assets/socials/clife.jpg'),
    ...
```

Also, you don't need to specify each asset file in the `pubspec.yaml` file. You can specify a folder, for example, the folder `lib/assets`, and then everything inside this folder will be accessible as an asset.

Finally, some people prefer to organize the code with `assets` in the same level as the `lib`.

Best!